# C# CS2066 Error. Cannot convert float to int

Tags: c#

```cs
float sum = 0, average=0;
float i;
float[] n = new float[5];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write("State number " + (i + 1) + ":");
    n[i] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    sum += n[i];
    average = sum / 5;
}

Console.WriteLine("Sum av all numbers: " + sum);
Console.WriteLine("Average value of all numbers: " + average);
Console.ReadKey();
```

I got error below

> CS9266 "Canot convert float to int"

on both instances of `n[i]`.

How do I fix that?

Comment: An index for an array needs to be an `int`, but you use a `float`. Make `i` an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your index variable `i` is currently declared as `float`, but it has to be an `int`

Change this declaration:

```
float i;
```

into this one:

```
int i;
```

Comment: And ideally only declare it within each loop - there's no point in it having greater scope than the loops.

Answer (score 0):

#### Easy way (suggested)

You should use `int i` instead of `float i` and it will be fixed!

Because array indexer `[]` takes `int` only

#### Alternative way (Not suggested)

So you should cast it to interger (`int`).

In C# You can cast using brackets and type, If i have `float` variable called `f`, It will be like this:

```cs
// Now "newF" will be integer
int newF = (int)f;
```

So you should use this code instead of `n[i]`

```cs
n[(int)i];
```

Your code will be like this:

```cs
float sum = 0, average=0;
float i;
float[] n = new float[5];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write("State number " + (i + 1) + ":");
    // Fix here...
    n[(int)i] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    // Fix here...
    sum += n[(int)i];
    average = sum / 5;
}

Console.WriteLine("Sum av all numbers: " + sum);
Console.WriteLine("Average value of all numbers: " + average);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: The "alternative" is far preferable - I would definitely reject the casting version in code review, for example. Having said that, I'd *also* reject the "just change the type" version, as it would be better to declare the variable inside the loop "header" itself.